# Unable to increment Firebase database from Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a data to Firebase and Increment its Child.

I'm getting it done until the value/Id is three. Then when I inserted a data for the fourth time, it replaces one of the data and can't increment more than three. So, what could be the problem?

> This is my Java Code

```
public class EnterInkhawmProg extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4, tv5, tv6, tv7;
    Button btn;
    Program program;
    long maxid = 0;

    DatabaseReference ref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inkhawp_prog);

        tv1 = findViewById(R.id.edittext_date);
        tv2 = findViewById(R.id.edittext_chairman);
        tv3 = findViewById(R.id.edittext_tantu);
        tv4 = findViewById(R.id.edittext_thilpek);
        tv5 = findViewById(R.id.edittext_biblechhiar);
        tv6 = findViewById(R.id.edittext_thusawitu);
        tv7 = findViewById(R.id.edittext_hunhmandan);

        program = new Program();

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Inkhawm");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    maxid = (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }
        });

        btn = findViewById(R.id.sub_btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                program.setDate(tv1.getText().toString().trim());
                program.setChairman(tv2.getText().toString().trim());
                program.setTantu(tv3.getText().toString().trim());
                program.setThilpek(tv4.getText().toString().trim());
                program.setBiblechhiarrual(tv5.getText().toString().trim());
                program.setThusawitu(tv6.getText().toString().trim());
                program.setHunhmandan(tv7.getText().toString().trim());

                ref.child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).setValue(program);
                Toast.makeText(EnterInkhawmProg.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        tv1.setText("");
                        tv2.setText("");
                        tv3.setText("");
                        tv4.setText("");
                        tv5.setText("");
                        tv6.setText("");
                        tv7.setText("");
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just replace this line

```
                ref.child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).setValue(program);
```

with

```
                ref.child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).push().setValue(program);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!! But now its not showing the list in my Recycler View anymore..Can you help me how to fixed it!